# java: confusing instructions, shopping cart program

Tags: java

My teacher gave me confusing instructions on this coding assignment. If you guys could help elaborate or give me tips, I'll provide what I have.

First of all the program is where I have to make 2 classes that will work with a big class to produce a shopping list where you can edit how much of each item you want. Have to take the name of an item, how many times its purchased, and how much each one costs.

I finished my first class, I'll post the entire coding and rules for the coding at the bottom of this question.

Okay so here's what I have. I'll go step by step.
Rule 1: A field private Purchase[] as an array of purchases.
Another int field that tracks how many purchases have actually been made

So I made this:

```
private int Purchase[];
private int purchaseCount;
```

Rule 2: Negative values do not make sense, so just reset those to zero if provided by user

Okay so in the first program I had to do the same thing, but I'm confused how to do it now.

I implemented the "reset to zero" in the modifiers, but now my teacher is not asking for modifiers. Am I supposed to put them anyway? I know I just have to put an "if blahblahblah < 0, then blahblahblah = 0" thing, but how do I go about that?

Rule 3: Accessor .length() method that returns your int field for how many purchases

```
public int Purchase(){
    return ;
}
```

I guess this is about all I know for that. I know I have to return something, not sure how to use length though. And I think there's a parameter.

Final Rule 4: Accessor .get(int) for the Purchase array, which needs a parameter that will index the array. So get(0) returns the first element (a Purchase object) of the array.

I think I understand this, but since I don't know how to do the last step, I haven't tried this yet. ".get(int)" what? So an accessor where I perform a .get(int) inside it? I don't know much about accessors, this is why I need this help. The rest of the program seems pretty simple for me, but this initial stuff confuses me. Thanks.

Rules for already completed class:

Three fields, a String for name of the purchase, int for units purchased, and a double for cost per unit.
• Standard accessors and modifier methods for each field.
• Negative values are not allowed, so change those to zero in all cases.
• Constructor to initialize these three fields (String, int, double) in that order.
• Constructor overload, (String, double) assumes the int quantity is zero.
• Default constructor that assumes name is “” and numbers are zero, must call the three argument constructor.
• A getCost method that is simply the number of units purchased times unit price.
• A toString method return a String with the item name followed by the unit price in parentheses

Completed program:

```
public class Purchase {
private String purchase;
private int unitsPurchased;
private double costPerUnit;

// Accessors
public String purchase() {
    return purchase;
}

public int unitsPurchased() {
    return unitsPurchased;
}

public double costPerUnit() {
    return costPerUnit;
}

// Modifiers
public void setPurchase(String purchase) {
    this.purchase = purchase;
}

public void setunitsPurchased(int unitsPurchased) {
    if (unitsPurchased < 0) {
        unitsPurchased = 0;
    }
    this.unitsPurchased = unitsPurchased;
}

public void setCostPerUnit(double costPerUnit) {
    if (costPerUnit < 0) {
        costPerUnit = 0;
    }
    this.costPerUnit = costPerUnit;
}
//constructors
public Purchase() {
    this("", 0, 0);
}

public Purchase(String initialPurchase, double initialCostPerUnit) {
    this.purchase = initialPurchase;
    this.unitsPurchased = 0;
    this.costPerUnit = initialCostPerUnit;
}

public Purchase(String initialPurchase, int initialUnitsPurchased, double initialCostPerUnit) {
    this.purchase = initialPurchase;
    this.unitsPurchased = initialUnitsPurchased;
    this.costPerUnit = initialCostPerUnit;
}

//end of everything I am sure about
//beginning of unsurety
public static double getCost(String purchase, int unitsPurchased, double costPerUnit) {
    return unitsPurchased * costPerUnit;
}
public static String toString(String purchase, int unitsPurchased, double costPerUnit){
    return purchase + costPerUnit;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so first rule 1 the code should look like:

```
private Purchase[] purchases;
private int purchaseCount;
```

Remember, in this case since you've already defined Purchase in your other java file, you're using it as a datatype, not as an identifier.

For rule 2, you're going to want that if statement in the access methods for `purchaseCount` as well as in the constructor.

Rule 3 is extremely vague...but my best guess is your teacher wants you to define a length method for that class, so that when you call say `purchases.length()` it returns the purchase count.

Again, rule 4 is vague, but my best guess is you need to define a get method for that class that just returns a value from your private purchases array using a given index.
Something like this:

```
public Purchase get(int index) {
    return purchases[index]
}
```

I hope this helps and good luck!!